# Moving object (pushpin) on map

Tags: c#, wpf, pushpin

I am reading a file of moving objects an put them in a dictionary (validMovingObjects). I represent each object as a pushpin on the map (baseMap). When an object changes its location (latitude or longitude), I update the validMovingObjects by (delete old instance and insert new one). Then I add all the objects in validMovingObjects to a map layer (objectsLayer) and yet to the baseMap. I do this with each single reading from the file by calling the refereshMap method below.

The problem:

The pushpins do not move. Only the last locations of the moving objects appear on the map as static pushpins.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

```
public void refereshMap(MapLayer objectsLayer, Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Map baseMap)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

    baseMap.Children.Clear();

    objectsLayer.Children.Clear();

    PositionOrigin objectPositionOrigin = PositionOrigin.Center;

    Location objectLocation;

    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, MovingObject> pair in validMovingObjects) 
    {        
        objectLocation = new Location(pair.Value.objectLatitude,pair.Value.objectLongitude);

        objectsLayer.AddChild(pair.Value.objectPin, objectLocation, objectPositionOrigin);
    }

    baseMap.Children.Add(objectsLayer);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are certainly blocking the UI thread by repeatedly calling your `refreshMap` method in a loop.

Consider updating the pushpin positions in a `Tick` event handler of a [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx).

Note also that it is not necessary to constantly remove and add pushpins to your `objectLayer`. Once a pushpin has been added to a MapLayer, you may just change its `MapLayer.Position` attached property.

Comment: a lot of thanks. Now the objects are moving. I will try to change the position only without removing them from the layer. Thanks Thanks Thanks.